# How to return a line when searching for text in that line

Tags: java, file, search, text, line

I want to get the line of a file, search through that line for specific text, and then return that line plus all the other lines in the file that have the same specific text in them.

I have this so far:

```
public String searchText(String text, String file)
{
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = null;

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            while(line.indexOf(text) > 0)
            {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();        
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

It has to be a function I can use when I need it.
I hope you guys understand what I want to do, and thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't told us what's wrong with the code you've posted, just what you want us to do for you.

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow. FYI you don't need to sign your name at the bottom of posts - they will automatically show your username at the bottom (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) for details)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your code is pretty good, and you're approaching the problem the correct way. You just need a few things to tidy it up, such as separating each line with a `\n` newline character, and calling `br.close();` when you've finished reading the file. I'm also not sure why you're using a `while(line.indexOf(text) > 0)` - it really should be an `if` statement.

Depending on how you want to use the lines once you've found them, you might find it nicer to use a `ArrayList<String>` and just `add()` the matched lines to it (rather than your current `StringBuffer`). This would probably be a better solution if you are going to use each line individually when you return from the method.

Answer (score 1):

There is not really a question, but what I see is that you are not appending a newline character which will cause the search results be on one long line. Add

```
sb.append('\n');
```

And change your inner `while` to an `if`. So the final code should be this:

```
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.indexOf(text) > 0)
        {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append('\n');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To be explicit, that inner while-loop is an infinite loop.
 
Because you are not changing `line` or `text` within the loop, if the condition is matched once, it will continue to be matched until you exceed the max size of `StringBuffer` or run out of memory.
So it's not just that that loop **should** be an if-statement - it **needs** to be.

Answer (score 0):

your on the correct track except the string returned by the function will be single line so you can not identify the number of lines.

so just add the new line character in final string after every append

Answer (score 0):

- Use Apache's IOUtils to read line by line from a `File` or to turn the
  whole `File` to a `String`.
- Use `String`'s `replaceAll` *method* to replace any `Sting` in the `File`
  changed to `String` using *regex* (which is very popular these days) or
  just plain `String`s